# SqlAlchemy update parameter must be a non-empty dictionary error in Airflow

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy, airflow

I'm currently running a scrapy spider in an Airflow webserver. In the pipelines file, I've got a function that takes the spider content in a dict and inserts the spider content in a MySQL db.

```
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        data = ItemAdapter(item)
        print(data)
        with self.engine.connect() as conn:
            statement = insert(self.db_table).values(**data)
            statement_duplicate_key = statement.on_duplicate_key_update(statement.inserted)
            conn.execute(statement_duplicate_key)
            
        return item
```

In my machine, which currently is running on SqlAlchemy 1.4.2, this code runs fine. In Airflow webserver which is in SqlAlchemy version 1.3.24 I get the following error:

```
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 857, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 150, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/crawler-sites-concorrentes/muffet/pipelines.py", line 177, in process_item
    statement_duplicate_key = statement.on_duplicate_key_update(statement.inserted)
  File "<string>", line 2, in on_duplicate_key_update
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 47, in _generative
    fn(self, *args[1:], **kw)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/dml.py", line 110, in on_duplicate_key_update
    self._post_values_clause = OnDuplicateClause(inserted_alias, values)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/dml.py", line 138, in __init__
    raise ValueError("update parameter must be a non-empty dictionary")
ValueError: update parameter must be a non-empty dictionary
```

I debuged the code to print the data and statements vars and they're not empty at all.

Any thoughts on how I can solve this?